# Proof of the completion of a metric space using cantors diagonal argument and showing a diagonal sequence is cauchy

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, cauchy-sequences

I am studying applied functional analysis out of Applied Analysis by John Hunter. In chp. 1 of the text it gives a proof for the completion of a metric space. I am having trouble with understanding where it actually proves the created metric space is complete. The text can be found here https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/book/ch1.pdf and part of the proof I am looking at starts on page 21.

So my questions are: Could someone please help me understand what exactly cantors diagonal argument is and why it would be used here? The only thing I have found so far was that it was another technique that was created to show the reals are uncountable. My second question is why is it important to show that a diagonal sequence is cauchy here? Finally, in the last part of the proof once we have shown the diagonal sequence is a cauchy sequence it goes on to show that $$d(x_{n,k},x_{k,k})\leq \frac{3}{N}$$ as $k\rightarrow\infty$, why do we do this? These questions are solely for deeper understanding and any help and comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you write out your $x_{n,k}$ in a tabular form such as

\begin{eqnarray}
 x_{1,1} & x_{1,2} & x_{1,3} & \ldots \\
 x_{2,1} & x_{2,2} & x_{2,3} & \ldots \\
 \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots
\end{eqnarray}

Then the diagonal sequence $x_{k,k}$ is being considered. That's the only relation to Cantor's diagonal argument (as you found, the one about uncountability of reals). It is a fairly loose connection that I would say it is not so important.

Second, $\tilde{X}$, the completion, is a set of Cauchy sequences with respect to the original space $(X,d)$. Why do we need to show that the diagonal sequence $x_{k,k}$ is Cauchy?  Let $x^d$ be the diagonal sequence. Then it would show that $x^d \in \tilde{X}$.  Recall that the goal is to show that $\tilde{X}$ is complete. We started with an arbitrary Cauchy (with respect to $\tilde{d}$) sequence of elements of $\tilde{X}$, and we want to show it converges to something in $\tilde{X}$. This $x^d$ that was constructed is the candidate element, but first we have to show that it is in $\tilde{X}$.

Third, the last part of the proof shows that $\tilde{x}_n$ converges to $x^d$ with respect to the completion metric $\tilde{d}$. If you chase the definition you will see why the book is doing that. That statement the OP references corresponds to the statement that $\tilde{d}(\tilde{x}_n,x^d) < 3/N$ for sufficiently large $n$ (aiming for the definition of convergence under $\tilde{d}$).

Be careful, as there are two levels of "Cauchy" in this proof. We show that $x^d$ is Cauchy with respect to $d$ (to show it is in $\tilde{X}$, as by definition $\tilde{X}$ is a collection of such sequences). The sequence $\tilde{x}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence with respect to $\tilde{d}$, and each element $\tilde{x}_n$ is a sequence itself which is Cauchy with respect to $d$  (A Cauchy sequence of Cauchy sequences... so you already have your hands full with separating these two levels!)

Comment: It is not true in general the the diagonal sequence of a Cauchy sequence of Cauchy sequences would be itself Cauchy. I did not look at the proof in the link but if it claims it then it is wrong. It is very easy to come up with a Cauchy sequence of sequences of rationals, each of which is Cauchy but such that the diagonal sequence is (e.g.) $1,2,3,\cdots, n,\cdots $

Comment: an aside remark: I find the construction of the completion using Cauchy filters to be technically simpler. It is less commonly presented though. However, it lends itself immediately to the similar construction of the completion of any uniform space.

Comment: @IttayWeiss the book first goes to subsequences of each of the individual sequences so that the diagonal will be Cauchy but yea, technical details

Comment: This was very helpful! Thank you.